# Bootstrap: convert date format- mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: jquery, django, date, django-bootstrap3

I am writing a Django web application and using Material Kit(Bootstrap) for front end. I want to display the date on the html in the format of **mm/dd/yyyy**.

**e.g.**

> 06/27/2018

I view date in database table, and it is already in the format of **mm/dd/yyyy**.

I have no idea why it's display in the .html in the format of

> June,28 2018

I think it's because of Material Kit, but I don't have idea any how to convert or override the function. Please help!

Comment: Isn’t this configured by the user? In the regional settings? If that’s the case it’s not up to you to change it....

Comment: @patrick so, there is no way to format the date?

Comment: how do you confirm that its passed in **mm/dd/yyyy** format

Comment: @Bijoy A bit of confusion. I view the database table and it's in **mm/dd/yyyy**. I am not sure it's passed in **mm/dd/yyyy** format.

Comment: can you print the date on view and check it on console ?

Comment: @Bijoy this is how it print in views.py: 2018-12-26, which is already the format I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set `USE_TZ = True` in settings.py then date and time information stored in database are in UTC, and transformed to the local date or time in templates w.r.t `TIME_ZONE` value given in `settings.py`

And also you can change the default date format, by defining [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) in **settings.py**, its default value is in `'N j, Y'` format. So you can try changing that to `DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'`

**OR**

If you want the date value to be in specific format in templates you can do

```
{{ date_value|date:'m/d/Y' }}
```

Comment: great to hear that ;-)